# Entity Framework make set of columns unique

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Say I have the following table with the following data

[image]

And I want to insert a new record of {Paul, 30, M}.

I want the DBContext to reject this. **Essentially what I want is the Name, Age and Gender to be unique in combo. No record can have the same name, age or gender.**

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

My Context is setup to just have a key

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

   public override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
         .HasKey(o => new { o.Id });
   }
}
```

Comment: [HasAlternateKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys)? (And note that there are variants where you have multiple properties). As a side note, in the real world it's almost always better to store the date of birth rather than age. Storing Age *guarantees* that, at some unknown point in the next 366 days, it'll spontaneously become inaccurate.

Comment: This isn't my actual model @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am just making a fake table to demo the purpose. I tried HasAlternateKey and that did not work for some reason

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is it possible that I'd need to do a DB migration for the changes to reflect? I am new to EF so not sure if that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More likely, you'll need either to have unique index or an alternate key.

With an [index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

   public override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
         .HasKey(o => new { o.Id });

      modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
         .HasIndex(p => new {p.Name, p.Gender, p.Age}).IsUnique();
   }
}
```

With an [alternate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

   public override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
         .HasKey(o => new { o.Id });

      modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
         .HasAlternateKey(p => new {p.Name, p.Gender, p.Age});
   }
}
```

Comment: To add on this, I used the HasAlternateKey. Now I have a question... is it possible to say specify a value for the inline properties. Say I want Name = Bob like this..............  modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
         .HasAlternateKey(p => new {p.Name = "Bob", p.Gender, p.Age});

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this statement?

Comment: Ignore my prior comment all good now thanks